Remove all unused components at once in Angular to improve time application speed
I have too many unused components in my angular appln v-8. I have to remove unused components and unused libraries as well. Is there a way to do this?
I am expecting my code to be clean so that I will get rid of all unwanted files.

you review the code, you delete the files, you profit from changes, you are done
